# svn_wc gem can not be imported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have a Ruby on Rails app, our development environment is set on macOS. I need a connection to the svn server that I use for storing files and so on.

The core problem I am facing is, despite I succeed all of the steps from the docs I can not import svn_wc gem in my controller.rb

Terminal output when I run `rails serve` is similar to this one

```
LoadError (cannot load such file -- svn/core)
```

I have this line in my Gemfile

```
gem 'svn_wc'
```

And had installed MacPorts for downloading Ruby bindings with the following command

```
sudo port install subversion-rubybindings
```

Comment: Please update with the controller code.

Comment: controller code only has this line require 'svn_wc', and even when I try to import this lib over irb I get exact same issue. So no need to add the controller code to the quesiton.

Comment: That gem is very old. My guess is that `subversion-rubybindings` does not have that `svn/core` anymore, or it's been renamed.

Comment: That can be correct, I hate non-well-documented libraries all around the world..

Answer (score 0):

The gem seems buggy and does not declare dependencies correctly. It requires `svn/core`, which is not present in the gem source code.

The gemspec does not declare any dependency either.

However, if you read the [README](https://github.com/dvwright/svn_wc), you'll see that you need SVN SWIG ruby binding (whatever that is) but also ruby 1.8.

Your best bet would be to find another gem, or even use something like git-svn and interact with it like git

Comment: Well, I read the README.md on this git repo and thought I should be installing those ruby bindings with MacPorts package manager. in order to do it, I used "sudo port install subversion-rubybindings" terminal command, but it did not chnaged anything on terminal output. I think, somehow MacPorts cannot install this required dependecy globally, therefore my app can not find this instaled library.